# How do I make this Navbar stick correctly?

Tags: html, css

The Navigation Bar sticks, but I followed some basic instructions on how to make it stick, which included `position: fixed; width: 100%; top: 0;`But the issue is that it covers up a portion of the page which is the height of it (40px) Now when someone clicks on the navbar links (which are linked to the `<h3>`'s), the `<h3>`'s are covered up by the Navbar. I don't know how to fix this.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="./stylesheets/main.css?v6.00000000000016" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="./favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/ico">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <a class="link linkanim" href="#introduction">Introduction</a>
      <a class="link linkanim" href="#begin">Getting Started</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section>
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <div class="text-container">
        <p id="notice"><span style="font-weight: bold;">NOTE</span>: This website will not work/render correctly on mobile devices, I'm just getting started on advanced HTML and CSS. Besides that, this website isn't interactive. Means that I haven't implemented JavaScript. I'm learning that next.</p>
        <h3 id="introduction">Introduction:</h3>
        <p id="hello">Content</p>
        <p id="improvements">Content mail to send emails:<a class="email-address" href="You seriously thought i was going to forget to remove my email here? hehheheheh!">Click here to send an E-Mail...</a></p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div class="text-container">
        <h3 id="begin">Let's begin</h3>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="icocredit">Title Favicon made by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/freepik" title="Freepik">Freepik</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon">www.flaticon.com</a> | Made by TimmSkiller (not Copyrighted) | My first real Website</div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-height: 40px;
}

main {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main section h1 {
  margin-top: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

main section div h3 {
  text-align: left;
  height: calc(23px + 19px);
}

.text-container p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.text-container {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#hello {
  height: 285px;
}

#notice {
  height: 76px;
}

#improvements {
  height: calc(19px + 133px)
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5.5px;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.email-address {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link {
  padding: 5.5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 12px;
  transition-duration: 0.75s;
}

.link:hover {
  background-color: #bebebe;
}

.link:active {
  background-color: #909090;
}

.icocredit {
  position: relative;
  font-size: small;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.icocredit a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

I don't want the navbar covering up the h3 elements, so they are readable.

EDIT: I have tried adding `padding-top: 40px` on `body {}`, doesn't work.
A link for proof: [GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/kEWEyxYauaI0yXxOUQ)
Edit 4: Code has changed and so did the question (50px > 40px)

Comment: It's a completely normal problem appearing as a consequence of your choice to have a "sticky" navigation bar. How you want to solve it is up to you -- you can pad the top of the document so the navigation bar doesn't cover actual content, that's what I would do if I were to use a sticky navigation bar. Also, investigate `position: sticky` -- it might be just what you want.

Comment: I am not understanding what you are attempting to accomplish. What is the problem you are encountering? What is the final goal?

Comment: As I clearly stated in the end of my question: "I need to NOT have the navbar take 50px of the page so that the h3 elements are visible and readable by the user who visits the site."

Comment: Ok, I am voting to close this. The question is unclear, you want a white black horse. You can't have it both ways -- if your navigation bar is at the top of the page, it will obscure the document content flowing behind it as you scroll, your document headings included. If you don't want it to do so, you need to either put the bar back into the flow (`position: static` or `position: initial`) or pad the top of your document with at least the height of the bar. The ball is in your court.

Comment: Okay, then what should I do if padding the top of the document doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid using JavaScript, you can simply add `padding-top: 50px` to Heading elements

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using JavaScript without altering your HTML structure, in a cleaner way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function () {
    window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 50); // Scroll the page 50 px up
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I really don't want to implement things that I don't understand, the answer above does it good enough. JavaScript is my goal when I can build websites perfectly with just HTML and CSS.

Comment: Then, you'll have to alter your structure, by using `<br>`s or by using `padding-top` which will add some extra white space vertically which you might not want.

Comment: The workaround I use for that is that I just compensate for that extra whitespace by removing 40px. of each item that has blank height space.

Answer (score 0):

If you want css based solution only then you can add this code in your css section

```
#introduction, #begin
{
  padding-top:50px;
}
```

**Result**

```css
html {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-height: 50px;
}

main {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main section h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

main section div h3 {
  text-align: left;
  height: calc(23px + 19px);
}

.text-container p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.text-container {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#hello {
  height: 285px;
}

#notice {
  height: 76px;
}

#improvements {
  height: calc(19px + 133px);
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5.5px;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.email-address {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link {
  padding: 5.5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 12px;
  transition-duration: 0.75s;
}

.link:hover {
  background-color: #bebebe;
}

.link:active {
  background-color: #909090;
}

.icocredit {
  position: relative;
  font-size: small;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.icocredit a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#introduction, #begin
{
  padding-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="./stylesheets/main.css?v6.00000000000016" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="./favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/ico">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <a class="link linkanim" href="#introduction">Introduction</a>
      <a class="link linkanim" href="#begin">Getting Started</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section>
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <div class="text-container">
        <p id="notice"><span style="font-weight: bold;">NOTE</span>: This website will not work/render correctly on mobile devices, I'm just getting started on advanced HTML and CSS. Besides that, this website isn't interactive. Means that I haven't implemented JavaScript.
          I'm learning that next.</p>
        <h3 id="introduction">Introduction:</h3>
        <p id="hello">Content</p>
        <p id="improvements">Content mail to send emails:<a class="email-address" href="You seriously thought i was going to forget to remove my email here? hehheheheh!">Click here to send an E-Mail...</a></p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div class="text-container">
        <h3 id="begin">Let's begin</h3>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="icocredit">Title Favicon made by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/freepik" title="Freepik">Freepik</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon">www.flaticon.com</a> | Made by TimmSkiller (not Copyrighted) | My first real Website</div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

If you do not want to alter your code structure or styling then you can go for solution provided by others using javascript

Comment: its working perfectly, I'll provide your code snippet

Comment: What does Bootstrap have to do with this? The question asks for pure HTML and CSS solution, neither is part of Bootstrap, and both are specified somewhere else.

Comment: I've mentioned bootstrap to provide weight to my answer as it has been documented that if you are using fix navbar then you should use padding top for body instead of giving margins to other elements

Comment: This still isn't working. I'll link a gif here:[GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/kEWEyxYauaI0yXxOUQ)

Comment: now check the code. I've given `padding-top:50px;` to `#introduction` and  `#begin`